# ng-repeat with boootstrap toggle strange behavior

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

below is my code

```
<div class='loadMainDiv' ng-controller="loadCntrl">
    <ul class='list-header' data-toggle="collapse" data-target='#{{schema.name}}' ng-repeat='schema in data'> {{schema.name}}
        <!--   <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target='#{{schema.name}}'>{{schema.name}}
         </li> -->

        <div id='{{schema.name}}' class="collapse in ">
            <ul ng-repeat="schemaEle in schema.value">
                <li class='list-item' ng-click='setSelected(schemaEle.name,$index)'><span ng-class="(selectedEle==schemaEle.name) ? 'selectedLi' :''">{{schemaEle.name+""}}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is output i am getting

Fruit

- Mango
- Banana

Language

- English
- Spanish

the behavior i am looking for is when i click on Fruit the DIV should be shrink and if click again it should expand. This is happening correctly but even if i click on individual sublist element i am getting same behaviour.
look strange for me ? what could be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div ng-repeat='schema in data'>
    <div class='list-header' data-toggle="collapse" data-target='#{{schema.name}}'>
        {{schema.name}}
    </div>
    <div id='{{schema.name}}' class="collapse in ">
        <ul ng-repeat="schemaEle in schema.value">
            <li class='list-item' ng-click='setSelected(schemaEle.name,$index); event.preventDefault();'><span ng-class="(selectedEle==schemaEle.name) ? 'selectedLi' :''">{{schemaEle.name+""}}</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```